# How to store date with optional time of day in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I want to store a date with optional time of day component. I want to be able to tell if the time of day is unknown or exact midnight.
Options

- DATE/TIMESTAMP + some boolean type indicating if the time of day is meaningful
- DATE where time component is always zero + some nullable field with the time component (VARCHAR2 with ISO format or NUMBER with seconds from midnight)
  Is there any better option?

Comment: Splitting the value into two fields is just going to cause you pain whenever you need the full value - you'd have to combine the date and time parts each time. If you need it you could have a virtual column that's set to Y/N or 0/1 if the time is midnight. But You may have values where the time is midnight *and* meaningful - assuming any 00:00:00 is a magic value sounds dangerous. So maybe better to set an extra column at the point of insert, when you know if a meaningful time was given? It's unclear how you get the values or when the time part is provided or omitted.

Comment: Yep,that's the problem with Oracle not supporting data types `DATE` and `TIME`, but only a datetime (that they inappropriately call `DATE`). I agree that having to combine date and time every other time may be a hassle, so yes, A DATE/TIMESTAMP plus some boolean. That is, Oracle supports `BOOLEAN` as of Oracle 23c. In any version older than this you'll have to use a number or character instead.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1 - Use an `INTERVAL` for the time component

Use a `DATE` column with a `NOT NULL` and `CHECK` constraint to ensure that the time component is always midnight for the date component.

Use an `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND` column, that can be `NULL` for the time component.

If you want the date-time as a string with optional time component then you can use a generated column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  date_value     DATE
                 NOT NULL
                 CONSTRAINT table_name__dv__chk
                   CHECK (date_value = TRUNC(date_value)),
  time_value     INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND
                 NULL,
  datetime_value VARCHAR2(19)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                   CAST(
                     TO_CHAR(
                       date_value + COALESCE(time_value, INTERVAL '0' HOUR), 
                       CASE 
                       WHEN time_value IS NOT NULL
                       THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
                       ELSE 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                       END
                     )
                     AS VARCHAR2(19)
                   )
                 )
);
```

Then you can insert the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (date_value, time_value)
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01', INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

and:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

outputs:

| DATE_VALUE | TIME_VALUE | DATETIME_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | +0 12:34:56.000000 | 1970-01-01 12:34:56 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | *null* | 1970-01-01 |

---

#### Option 2 - Use a flag to show if the time is present

You can store the value as a `DATE` and then have a flag column to show if you can ignore the time components of that date.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (
  date_value     DATE
                 NOT NULL,
  has_time_value VARCHAR2(1)
                 NOT NULL
                 CONSTRAINT table_name2__htv__chk
                   CHECK (has_time_value IN ('Y', 'N')),
  datetime_value VARCHAR2(19)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                   CAST(
                     TO_CHAR(
                       date_value, 
                       CASE has_time_value
                       WHEN 'Y'
                       THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
                       ELSE 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                       END
                     )
                     AS VARCHAR2(19)
                   )
                 )
);
```

Then, if you have the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name2 (date_value, has_time_value)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 12:34:56', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01', 'N' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name2;
```

Outputs:

| DATE_VALUE | HAS_TIME_VALUE | DATETIME_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 12:34:56 | Y | 1970-01-01 12:34:56 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | N | 1970-01-01 |

*Note: If you need to, you could add additional constraints so that if `has_time_value` is `'N'` then the time component of the date value must be midnight so that users cannot enter random times-of-day on values that will be ignored.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jvV95JXx)